# Element mapping with composite primary key with Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, mapping, composite-key

I'm converting some C# with NHibernate XML mapping to Java with Annotations mapping, and there's an entity I've tried converting without success. We have a MAIN_TABLE, a JOIN_TABLE and a THIRD_TABLE. One record from MAIN_TABLE can have many from THIRD_TABLE, and their relation is stored on JOIN_TABLE, which has only three columns: a primary key composed of the keys from MAIN_TABLE and THIRD_TABLE, and a third row with some irrelevant additional data. This is the original NHibernate XML mapping:

```
<class name="MainTable" table="MAIN_TABLE" mutable="false">
<id name="Id" column="rvcplc" type="int" length="10">
  <generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<bag name="JoinedRecords" table="JOIN_TABLE" order-by="main_table_id">
  <key column="main_table_id" not-null="true"/>
  <composite-element class="JoinTable">
    <parent name="parentRecord"/>
    <many-to-one name="ThirdTable" column="third_table_id"/>
  </composite-element>
</bag>
```

And this is the current state of my code:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="MAIN_TABLE")
@Immutable
public class MainTable extends BusinessEntity implements IMainTable
{
   @Id
   @Type(type = "LongToNull")
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id; 

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="JOIN_TABLE", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="main_table_id")})
   private List<IJoinTable> joinedRecords = new ArrayList<IJoinTable>();
}

@Embeddable()
@Table(name = "JOIN_TABLE")
@Immutable
public class JoinTable implements Serializable, IJoinTable
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Id
    private JoinTablePK pkId;

    @Parent
    @Column(name = "main_table_id")
    private IMainTable parentRecord;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ThirdTable.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "third_table_id")
    private IThirdTable thirdTable;

    public static class JoinTablePK implements Serializable
    {
          // foo
    }
}
```

When I try to unit test this association, simply loading a known MainTable entity and asserting it has three children JoinTable objects in its collection fails, with a "Could not initialize a collection" error. This is my best code, though, because other attempts have made ALL my tests fail, as it happens when you have a wrong mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would try to do it (I'll be using simple classes in the code, hopefully super classes and interfaces aren't relevant to the issue).

There are two options. First one, the easier one, is if that "irrelevant additional data" in `JOIN_TABLE` is really irrelevant to the model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MAIN_TABLE")
public class MainTable {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "LongToNull")
    private long id; 

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "JOIN_TABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "JOIN_TABLE_ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "THIRD_TABLE_ID")
    private List<ThirdTable> thirdTableRecords = new ArrayList<ThirdTable>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="THIRD_TABLE")
public class ThirdTable {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "LongToNull")
    private long id; 

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "thirdTableRecords")
    private List<MainTable> mainTableRecords = new ArrayList<MainTable>();

    ...
}
```

If "irrelevant additional data" still has to be modeled, then entities would look something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MAIN_TABLE")
public class MainTable {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "LongToNull")
    private long id; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainTable")
    private List<JoinTable> joinTableRecords = new ArrayList<JoinTable>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="THIRD_TABLE")
public class ThirdTable {
    @Id
    @Type(type = "LongToNull")
    private long id; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "thirdTable")
    private List<JoinTable> joinTableRecords = new ArrayList<joinTable>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="JOIN_TABLE")
public class JoinTable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private JoinTablePK pkId;

    private String irrelevantData;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_TABLE_ID", insertable = false, updateable = false)
    private MainTable mainTable;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "THIRD_TABLE_ID", insertable = false, updateable = false)
    private ThirdTable thirdTable;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class JoinTablePK {
    @Column(name = "MAIN_TABLE_ID")
    private Long mainTableId;

    @Column(name = "THIRD_TABLE_ID")
    private Long thirdTableId;

    // getters and setters
}
```

`insertable = false` and `updateable = false` are there because you are mapping two fields to the same column, and there can be only one writable field for one column.

I didn't test the code, so I would be surprised if it would work as it is, but hopefully it does give you some guidelines to follow, and you'll get at least a few steps closer to the solution.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. Sadly, "irrelevant additional data" has to be mapped because it's irrelevant for the relationship, but the data contained has to be used in the code. So I've tried your second example and I get an "AnnotationException: JoinTable$JoinTablePK has no persistent id property" Any ideas?

Comment: I knew it wouldn't work as it is :) By looking at similar problems, do you have getters and setters in `JoinTablePK` class, for `mainTableId` and `thirdTableId`?

Comment: @Picacodigos I've added `JoinTablePK` code for reference, to have a complete picture and a full base for next attempts

Comment: I got it. Finally, I got it. I haven't used your approach, instead I've used this: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/ I'm going to post another reply with the complete solution for my other approach in case is useful to others, but your solution also works, so I'll check it as the right one. The bounty is yours. =) MANY THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

There's another approach besides the one suggested by Predrag Maric. It's detailed here: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

I've added this reply in case the link is useful to anyone else. This is my complete code:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name="MAIN_TABLE")
@Immutable
public class MainTable extends BusinessEntity implements IMainTable
{
    @Id
    @Type(type = "LongToNull")
    @Column(name = "MAIN_TABLE_ID")
    private long id; 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.parentRecord", targetEntity =     JoinTable.class)
    private List<IJoinTable> joinedRecords = new ArrayList<IJoinTable>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "JOIN_TABLE")
@AssociationOverrides({
     @AssociationOverride(name="pk.parentMainTable", joinColumns =   @JoinColumn(name="MAIN_TABLE_ID")),
     @AssociationOverride(name="pk.parentThirdTable", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="THIRD_TABLE_ID"))
      })
public class JoinTable implements Serializable, IJoinTable
{
    private JoinTablePK pkId;
    private BigDecimal irrelevantData;

    // Ctor
    public JoinTable(MainTable mainTable, ThirdTable thirdTable)
    {
        pk = new JoinTablePK(mainTable, thirdTable);
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public JoinTablePK getPk()
    {
        return pk;
    }

    // here goes the setter, no annotations

    @Transient
    public IMainTable getMainTable()
    {
        return getPk().getMainTable();
    }

    // here goes the setter, no annotations

    @Transient
    public IThirdTable getThirdTable()
    {
        return getPk().getThirdTable();
    }

    // here goes the setter, no annotations

    @Column(name = "JOIN_TABLE_IRRELEVANT_DATA")
    public BigDecimal getIrrelevantData()
    {
        return irrelevantData;
    }

    // here goes the setter, no annotations

    /**
    * PRIMARY KEY CLASS
    */
    @Embeddable
    public static class JoinTablePK implements Serializable
    {
      private MainTable parentMainTable;

      @ManyToOne
      public MainTable getParentMainTable()
      {
        return parentMainTable;
      }

      // here goes the setter, no annotations

      private ThirdTable parentThirdTable;

      @ManyToOne
      public ThirdTable getParentThirdTable()
      {
        return parentThirdTable();
      }

      // here goes the setter, no annotations

      // empty ctor
      public JoinTablePK() {}

      // ctor with parameters
      public JoinTablePK(MainTable parentMainTable, ThirdTable parentThirdTable)
      {
        this.parentMainTable = parentMainTable;
        this.parentThirdTable = parentThirdTable;
      }

      // rest of the class, implement equals() and hashCode()
    }
}
```